# Targeting an element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've had a good look around and have found many different ways to target an element, but none for what im looking to do.

Basically, i want to toggle the display of a `<section>` by using a checkbox input.

my html code is...

```
<li><input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="contacttog"><label for="contacttog">Contact</label></li>              
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<section class="hiddencontact" id="hiddencontact"></section>
```

So I want to use the input to toggle `.hiddencontact`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know I can easily use JS to do this.
I've tried..

```
    input.toggle {
    display: none;
}
input.toggle + .hiddencontact {
    height: 200px; margin: .2rem; overflow: hidden;
}

input.toggle:checked .hiddencontact {
    display: block;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

to no avail, clearly

Comment: The `li/input` has no direct relationship to the 'section' (they are not siblings or parent/child) so it can't affect it.

Comment: I did wonder that, so. js it is?

Comment: Given the current HTML...yes.

Comment: @Olleh if using JS, it doesn't matter what kind of HTML structure you have, it just need to be valid.

Comment: If you re-arrange your HTML, you might accomlish the desired result with CSS. Something like: `.toggle:checked + .hiddencontact` or `.toggle:checked ~ .hiddencontact`

Comment: [Do you mean something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/6M2Ua/)